# How to remove Annotation from Map in Swift 2 [MapKit]

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, mapkit, swift2

I can add Annotation on MapView using "first" button, but I would like to add a new option which enables the removing of the annotation using the "second" button. I have no problem with adding annotation, but I cannot remove it from the map view. Can somebody help me in it?

Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var mapViewOutlet: MKMapView!

var lm = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.lm.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    mapViewOutlet.showsUserLocation = true
    mapViewOutlet.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingMode.Follow

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// HERE IS FUNCTION ADDANNOTATION

@IBAction func tagMyCar(sender: UIButton) {

    let coordinate = lm.location?.coordinate


    let CarCoordinates = CarAdnotaion(coordinate: coordinate!)

    mapViewOutlet.addAnnotation(CarCoordinates)

    let region = CLCircularRegion(center: coordinate!, radius: 5, identifier: "My Car")

    region.notifyOnEntry = true
    region.notifyOnExit = true

    lm.startMonitoringForRegion(region)

}

// HERE IS FUNCTION REMOVEANNOTATION

@IBAction func removeAnnotationfromMap(sender: AnyObject) {

    let region = CLCircularRegion(center: (lm.location?.coordinate)!, radius: 5, identifier: "Mój samochód")

    self.mapViewOutlet.removeAnnotation(CarAdnotaion(coordinate: (lm.location?.coordinate)!))

    lm.stopMonitoringForRegion(region)

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
self.mapViewOutlet.removeAnnotation(CarAdnotaion(coordinate: (lm.location?.coordinate)!))
```

You are removing annotation that you just created in this very statemen. Instead, move `let CarCoordinates` up (and give it more sensible name and lowercase letter in the beginning). Then call removeAnnotation on that object.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution of my problem. It works!

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var mapViewOutlet: MKMapView!

let lm = CLLocationManager()
var carAnnotation: CarAnnotationOnMap?
var region: CLCircularRegion?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.lm.requestAlwaysAuthorization()


    mapViewOutlet.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingMode.Follow
    mapViewOutlet.showsUserLocation = true

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// ADD ANNOTATION ON MAP

@IBAction func tagMyCar(sender: UIButton) {

    let coordinates = lm.location?.coordinate
    carAnnotation = CarAnnotationOnMap(coordinates: coordinates!)

    region = CLCircularRegion(center: coordinates!, radius: 5, identifier: "My Zone")


    region!.notifyOnEntry = true
    region!.notifyOnExit = true
    self.lm.startMonitoringForRegion(region!)

    mapViewOutlet.addAnnotation(carAnnotation!)

}

// REMOVE ANNOTATION FROM MAP

@IBAction func removePinFromMyCar(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.lm.stopMonitoringForRegion(region!)
    mapViewOutlet.removeAnnotation(carAnnotation!)

}

}
```